# SSOJAASUserRealm example

Tags: jetty

I am completely new to Jetty so I apologize in advance for my n00bess. I have Jetty which uses JAASRealm for authentication, I want to implement SSO so I was looking at [SSOJAASUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/plus/jaas/SSOJAASUserRealm.html)  but there is no good documentation that would help me understand how to use it. Jetty site has documentation for [HashSSORealm](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Single+Sign+On+-+Jetty+HashSSORealm) but not for SSOJAASUserRealm.

It also appears to me looking at the java docs for [JAASUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/plus/jaas/JAASUserRealm.html) and [HashUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/security/HashUserRealm.html) that JAASUserRealm does not implement SSORealm interface so even if I use [SSOJAASUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/plus/jaas/SSOJAASUserRealm.html)  I have to  stick with [HashUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/security/HashUserRealm.html).

Is there any example on how to use [SSOJAASUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/plus/jaas/SSOJAASUserRealm.html)  with 
[JAASUserRealm](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/plus/jaas/JAASUserRealm.html) ?

I am using Jetty 6.

Comment: I am just going to recommend you use a version of jetty that is at least getting maintenance releases still.  Jetty 7.6.5 is the latest release for servlet api 2.5 and 8.1.5 for servlet 3.0 support.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JAAS

Comment: Unfortunately, using jetty 6 is one of the 'requirements' that we have, mainly due to the custom code we have in there. I do completely agree with you and personally not a big fan of any custom changes.

Comment: fair enough, jetty users list might put you in touch with more jetty6 users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the SSOJAASUserRealm implementation is not complete. I got a clue from the HashSSORealm which also implements SSORealm. You can look at the HashSSORealm.java class and modify it for your use case. All you need to do is implement the setSingleSignOn() and getSingleSignOn() methods. I did not use the cookie (as in the HashSSORealm class) but instead used my session id.